# Ajax request in a "for" loop. Counter's unexpected behaviour

Tags: jquery, ajax, performance

I have problems with the following block of code:

```
function MediaImport4pr(nbr) {
    $("#latestPr ul.list").empty();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/aQ_OX/local/LATESTPR/LatestPr.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
            //var array = data.split(',');
            var array = data;
            var arrayWithRightNumberOfPr = ["tst4_01-11-2014.aspx", "tst1_11-06-2014.aspx", "tst2_10-05-2014.aspx", "tst5_27-03-2014.aspx"];
            for (im = 0; im < arrayWithRightNumberOfPr.length; im++) {
                AjaxRequest(im, arrayWithRightNumberOfPr);
            }


        }
    });
}



function AjaxRequest(im, array) {
    $.get("/aQ_OX/LOCAL/ASPXGENERATED/" + array[im], function(data) {
        var targetTitle = $(data).find('#title').html();
        var targetDate = $(data).find('#date').html();
        var targetPdf = $(data).find('#pdf').html();

        if (targetPdf != "noPDF") {
            $("#latestPr ul.list").append("<li class='item pr" + im + "'><p class='date'>" + targetDate + "</p><ul><li class='title'><a class='title' href='/aQ_OX/LOCAL/ASPXGENERATED/" + array[im - 1] + "'>" + targetTitle + "</a></li><li class='pdf'><a class='pdf' href='" + targetPdf + "'>PDF</a></li></ul></li>");
        } else {
            $("#latestPr ul.list").append("<li class='item pr" + im + "'><p class='date'>" + targetDate + "</p><ul><li class='title'><a class='title' href='/aQ_OX/LOCAL/ASPXGENERATED/" + array[im - 1] + "'>" + targetTitle + "</a></li></ul></li>");
        }
    });
}
```

Basically, this code generates "li" tags, the problem is the "for" loop starts with very different numbers everytime it's run.
I simply expected 0,1,2,3 etc but sometimes i have 0,1,3,4 or 2,3,0,1 and so on ...

1. What is the problem in my code ?
2. except this error, this code works well but i have a performance problem, it takes 3 seconds for being displayed. it's way too long. I'm not looking for the most performant code but something faster would be appreciated!
   Thanks for your recommandations...

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous, so it doesnt necessarily executes after each other

Comment: What devqon said, your ajax calls are not going to guarantee the same order every time. What you should be doing is preloading this information and then looping through after you have all the elements.

Comment: Is there any other solutions than preloading all the elements ?

Answer (score 1):

Not the actual issue, but good practice: Make the loop counter `im` local by adding `var` (it is currently a global so is shared across all parallel calls to MediaImport4pr)

```
for (var im = 0; im < arrayWithRightNumberOfPr.length; im++)
```

**Order is not guaranteed:**

The problem is purely down to expecting the order of your Ajax results to be the same as the requests... But Ajax will not guarantee which requests will return first. You need to ensure you have enough information in the response to insert the results into the display in the desired order (and not assume anything about the incoming order).

**Reduce the requests:**

The second issue of timing is down to the response time of your server and the number of requests. Check the network traffic and timings for the multiple requests you are sending (e.g. via the F12 Chrome debug tools, Network tab).

Basically you have "a lot" of network calls happening and the browser will limit the number of simultaneous Ajax calls). Maybe combine into fewer calls returning more data each? A single request with 10 times the data is preferable to 10 smaller calls in this case. This will also solve the ordering issue as the array of returned results will be predefined by the server :)

Comment: Thanks for this helpful explanation but i still don't know how i could increase the speed in my context ...

Comment: To get a significant speed increase you need to reduce the number of separate Ajax calls as that has a large overhead and many browsers will only allow a few simultaneous requests so they will queue up. Use a single mega-request to return an array of multiple requests together, If you can provide sample data I may be able to help, but this needs changes to both the client and server code.